# Problem with java classes generation from wsdl

Tags: java, maven, gradle, wsdl, wsimport

I am trying to generate Java classes from this WSDL https://sedo.fss.ru/sedo-gateway/api/soap/SedoGateway?wsdl. I tried to do it with wsdl2java util, wsimport util but I get an error all the time:

> Fail to create wsdl definition: WSDLException: Problem parsing
> 'http://sedo.fss.ru/sedo-gateway/api/soap/SedoGateway?wsdl=../Faults.wsdl'
> The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag
> "/hr".

I also tried to do it with different Maven plugins - same result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This sounds like your code received some HTML error page containing an `<hr>` instead of the WSDL. Maybe you need to configure a proxy or something?